# Rasterizing a Cubic Polynomial

Tags: image, graphics, image-processing, polynomial-math, rasterizing

Given a cubic polynomial estimated using least-squares regression, I am interested in a simple algorithm that rasterizes the curve to display in an image. My initial intuition is to sample the curve for every integer value of *x*, but this leaves gaps in regions of high slope. Because the cubic can have regions of arbitrarily high slope, further increasing the sample rate would only be a stop-gap measure.

How do professional graphing tools, such as Matlab and Gnuplot solve this problem? Are there any "good enough" approximations that are suitable for real-time applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by drawing a line between the points, but it won't look smooth.

A better looking solution would be to supersample in the *x* dimension, draw a line with thickness along that dimension, then subsampling back to the scale you want to display.

Comment: Supersampling would definitely improve the rendering accuracy, but the fundamental problem still exists. A near-vertical line, for example, would require an unbounded number of samples to represent. Perhaps there is a way to re-parameterize the cubic so this is not an issue?

Comment: Connect the points with lines, don't just plot the individual points. This is how the (cubic) splines screen saver works.